# C++ How to declare as atribute, a pointer to my own type, using templates

Tags: c++, pointers, attributes

This is my problem: I have a class "Nodo" (to make BSTs) which has an array of pointers to its same type as attribute, and then I have a son class "NodoAvl" (to make AVL Trees) which have to inherit that atribute, but the pointers must point to its same type, that is, to point to a "NodoAvl". There is any way to do this?  Maybe with my code, I can explain it better:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Nodo
 {
 protected:
  T d;
  "my_own_type" *h[2] = {NULL};  // Here I need pointers to my own type 
                                 // so Nodo has 2 pointers to Nodo
                                 // and NodoAvl has 2 pointers to NodoAvl
 public:
  Nodo(T dato = T()) { d = dato; }
 };

template <class T>
class NodoAvl : public Nodo<T>
 {
 protected:
  int alt = 0;
 public:
  NodoAvl (T dato = T()): Nodo<T>(dato) {}
  int altu () {return alt;}
 };
```

I will be gratefull for your help.

---

--- UPDATE ---

I just  have read about CRTP (thanks *Some programmer dude*) and although I didn't understand all its utility, I found that it could solve my problem. I decided to make "Nodo" a big-father class adding one label in its template "TN" (type of node), so my array of pointers could be declared as TN*. Then I created 2 son class: NodoBst and NodoAvl, each one inherit from "Nodo" but labeled with its respective type of node in the template. Again my code will explain better my idea.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, class TN>
class Nodo
 {
 protected:
  T d;
  TN *h[2] = {NULL};
 public:
  Nodo(T dato = T()) { d = dato; }
 };

template <class T>
class NodoBst : public Nodo<T,NodoBst<T>>
 {
 protected:
 public:
  NodoBst (T dato = T()): Nodo<T,NodoBst<T>>(dato) {}
 };

template <class T>
class NodoAvl : public Nodo<T, NodoAvl<T>>
 {
 protected:
  int alt = 0;
 public:
  NodoAvl (T dato = T()): Nodo<T,NodoAvl<T>>(dato) {}
  int altu () {return alt;}
 };

int main ()
 {
 NodoAvl<int> * narval = new NodoAvl<int>(10);
 cout << narval->altu();
 }
```

It has worked, but I want to know if it's a good practice or I'm making future problems. I want add more methods to the father class which works with the array of pointers and all of them are the same in any kind of node (ej: update the pointers, dereference them, kill them, etc). What would you do if you had to solve this problem? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: What do you mean by "attribute" in this regard?

Comment: Sorry, I think the best word would be "member".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the obvious way:

```
Nodo<T>* h[2];
```

But you can also do it simply by using the class name alone:

```
Nodo* h[2];
```

Comment: Yes, but in that case, NodoAvl will inherit pointers to "Nodo" and not pointers to "NodoAvl". I need that each kind of object has pointers to its same kind of object

Comment: @AliRojas I think you then are looking for the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! Probably that solves my problem. Please read my update and tell me if that is that you mean it, or if you find any problem. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the dynamic type of a class in the way you suggest. Every `Nodo<T>` class must be the same class with the same declarations. It cannot know if a particular `Nodo<T>` is being used as a base class or not. So it cannot change its own definition to match who is deriving from it.

The only way to do what you're suggesting is to *tell it* what class it is derived from, by passing the derived class as a template parameter. And it's not possible to pass one's own class as a template parameter to one's self. So you would need to have a specialization of `Nodo` that doesn't take a derived class. And you should mark it `final` to keep people from deriving from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I didn't understand so well the last part. Could you show me a simple example please? (anyone that helps me understand the idea) I will be gratefull.

Comment: Nicol Bolas, I just read about CRTP and it seems to be a case which an template acepts as parameter to it self. Please read my update and tell me if you found any problem. I'm very noob in this teme. Thanks a lot!